# Or HTML entity in XML in Android

Tags: android, html, xml

I found [List of XML and HTML character entity references](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references#Predefined_entities_in_XML)

I look for `OR` ( `||` ) HTML entity name : https://www.fileformat.info/format/w3c/htmlentity.htm to use in Android xml file for `dataBinding`

But I couldn't find it. Can you help me?

Comment: check [`vertical bar &#124;   |`](https://www.degraeve.com/reference/specialcharacters.php)

Answer (score 0):

Check this [Wikipedia Page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertical_bar#Encoding)

```
The vertical bar is encoded in Unicode at U+007C | VERTICAL LINE (124decimal · HTML &#124;
```